# closed points of a scheme and k-points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

So I was reading the book "Algebraic Geometry" by Görtz and Wedhorn.

I have trouble with Corollary 3.36 on Page 80. The statement is:

Let $X$ be a scheme locally of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $x \in X$ and $\kappa(x)$ be the residue field at $x$. Then the following equalities hold:

$$\{x \in X\; |\; x\; \text{is closed}\} = \{x \in X\; |\; k = \kappa(x)\} = \text{Hom}_{k}(\text{Spec}(k),X)$$

Now what I can prove is the following:

If $x$ is closed, then by Proposition 3.33, $\kappa(x)$ is finite extension of $k$ and hence $k = \kappa(x)$ as $k$ is algebraically closed.

If $k = \kappa(x)$, then by Proposition 3.8 we have a map from $\text{Spec}(k)$ to $X$.

Now the problem is:

If we have a morphism from $\text{Spec}(k)$ to $X$ with image $x$, then we have again by Proposition 3.8 a map from $\kappa(x)$ to $k$. However, I do not see why this should imply that $\kappa(x) = k$ or that $x$ is closed.

Ideas:

Since we have $k \to \kappa(x) \to k$ and both maps are injective, I thought that this might imply that they are isomorphic. However, that turns out to be not true. Is it true in the special case where $k$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: You have more than just injective maps: the composition $k\to \kappa (x)\to k $ is the identity on $k $.

Comment: @Stahl Stupendous response--that's a 10.

Comment: @Stahl If only I could see why that is true...

Comment: @VishalGupta First of all $\operatorname{Spec}(k)=\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(x))$ is the scheme $\{x\}$, and $\operatorname{Spec}(k)\to X$ is the inclusion of schemes $\{x\}\to X$. From this follows the statement of Stahl. ;)

Comment: @Armandoj18eos That is exactly the question! Why is $\text{Spec}(k) = \text{Spec}(\kappa(x)) = \{x\}$ as schemes? They are same as topological spaces but the section at the single point of $\text{Spec}(F)$, for any field $F$, is the field $F$ itself. And we do not know a priori that $k = \kappa(x)$.

Comment: The map $\operatorname{Spec}k\to X$ is a map of $k$-schemes, so $\operatorname{Spec}k\to X\to\operatorname{Spec}k$ is the identity (you haven't specified a structure map $\operatorname{Spec}k\to\operatorname{Spec}k$, but the only canonical choice is the identity).

Comment: @Stahl Thanks, I see it now. The mistake I was making is that I was forgetting that the map $k \to \kappa(x)$ comes from the structure morphism of $X$ as a $k-$scheme.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in X$ is a closed point hence $\{x\}\cong\textrm{Spec }k(x)$.

Comment: To see this, choice $U=\textrm{Spec }A$ containing $x$. Hence $x=\mathfrak{m}$ corresponds to maximal ideal in $A$ and $$A/\mathfrak{m}=A_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}}=k(x).$$