# For algebraically closed field $F$, if there are homomorphisms $E \to F$ and $F \to E$, then $F\cong E$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field and $E$ a field. Assume that there are homomorphisms(so monomorphisms)
$i : E \to F$ and $j:F \to E$.

Then $j$ is an isomorphism?

My question origianes from next statement (Gortz, Algebraic Geometry, Corollary 3.36)

[image]

Here, the Proposition 3.8. is, :

[image]

I'm trying to understand the underlined equality.

By the Proposition 3.8., it suffices to show that there exists a bijection

$$ \{x\in X ; i_x : k \cong \kappa(x) \} \cong \{(x,\iota) ; x\in X, \iota : \kappa(x) \to k \}$$

(where $i_x : k \hookrightarrow \kappa(x)$ is the natural homomorphism (Gortz's book prop.3.33 and p.60 (3.4.2) ) ; i.e, applying the global section functor $\Gamma$ to $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(x)) \to X \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$)

Let's define $\eta : \{x\in X ; i_x : k \cong \kappa(x) \} \to \{(x,\iota) ; x\in X, \iota : \kappa(x) \to k \}$ by $ x \mapsto (x, i_x^{-1})$. I'm trying to show that this map is a bijection.

For showing the surjectivity, I'm trying to show that for $(x, \iota)$, $x$ satisfies that the $i_x : k \hookrightarrow \kappa(x)$ is an isomorphism. If our above question is true, then we may show this. And our question is true? If not, how can we show the underlined statement?

Can anyone help ?

**Modified Question** : In the above question, if furthermore $i$, $j$ satisfy $i∘j=id_F$, then $j$ is an isomorphism?

If this question is true, then by reffering [closed points of a scheme and k-points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034857/closed-points-of-a-scheme-and-k-points), we can deduce the underlined equality.

Comment: For the first question, $j$ may not be an isomorphism. Consider $E=F=\overline{k(X_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N)}$ and some maps that $i,j$ which extend, repsetively, the map $f(X_{i_1},\cdots,X_{i_s})\mapsto f(X_{2i_1},\cdots, X_{2i_s})$ and the map $f(X_{i_1},\cdots,X_{i_s})\mapsto f(X_{3i_1},\cdots, X_{3i_s})$ from $k(X_n\,:\,n\in\Bbb N)$ to $E$ and $F$.

Comment: It's also possible that $E$ and $F$ aren't isomorphic. Take the same $E$ as before, $F=E(T)$, $i'$ the obvious immersion and $j'\left(\frac{\sum_{s=0}^m a_sT^s}{\sum_{r=0}^h b_rT^r}\right)=\frac{\sum_{s=0}^m j(a_s)X_7^s}{\sum_{r=0}^h j(b_r)X_7^r}$, where $j:E\to E$ is the same as before.

Comment: What's true is that if $E$ and $F$ are both algebraically closed and there are homomorphisms $E\to F$ and $F\to E$, then $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic, although not necessarily by any of the previously mentioned homomorphisms.

Comment: Can I ask more question? How about case that $i : E \to F$, $j : F\to E$ satisfy $i\circ j = id_{F}$? In this case $E \cong F$ ($j$ isomorphism)?

Comment: This is just a set-theoretic matter: $i\circ j=id_F$ implies that $i$ is surjective and, therefore, bijective. So $j=i^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, O.k. Thank you.~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Consider $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}(t) \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$.

Since $\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$ and $\mathbb{C} $ are both algebraically closed, and have the same characteristic and the same transcendence degree over the prime field, they are isomorphic. However, $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$