# Confusion on the objects $\operatorname{Ob} (Sch_S)$ of the Category of $S$-schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

Let $S$ be some scheme. What are the objects $\operatorname{Ob} (Sch_S)$ of the Category of Schemes over $S$, $Sch_S$?

In Vakil, we have (6.3.7) that "the objects [of $Sch_S$] are [scheme] morphisms of the form $X\rightarrow S$ [called structure maps]." Hartshorne bears this out: "a scheme $X$ over $S$ is a scheme $X$, together with a morphism $X\rightarrow S$."

Does this imply that for any one scheme $X$ there could a priori be *two different* objects of the category, $X\rightarrow_\phi S$ and $X\rightarrow_\psi S$? This seems odd, given that morphisms in $Sch_S$ must by definition commute with structure maps, and so these objects are not isomorphic; if they were then would have to commute:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X@>>{\simeq}> X\\
@VV{\phi}V @VV{\psi}V \\
S @>>{\simeq}> S
\end{CD}$$

Is this truly the definition, or am I missing some subtlety? If this is the correct definition, how does one interpret an expression such as $\operatorname{Hom}_S(S,X)$, where $\operatorname{Hom}_S$ denotes morphisms of $S$-schemes? It seems to depend on the structure morphisms, in which case expressions (for an alg closed field $k$) like $\{x\in X \text{ closed}\}=\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ confuse me, as showing

$\{x\in X \text{ closed}\}\subset \operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ seems to require that $\operatorname{Spec} k\simeq_\phi \operatorname{Spec} k$, $\phi$ the identity, is the implied structure morphism for $\operatorname{Spec} k$, whereas

$\{x\in X \text{ closed}\}\supset \operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ seems to require that the structure morphism of $\operatorname{Spec} k$ is chosen based on the implied structure map of $X$: so that each $x$ commutes with the structure morphism of $X$ in the diagram of the canonical map $i_x: \operatorname{Spec} k=\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x)\rightarrow X$ over $\operatorname{Spec} k$ (e.g. from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034857/closed-points-of-a-scheme-and-k-points)).

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you're trying to say in the final paragraph.  Maybe you are missing the fact the canonical maps $i_x$ which you mention *are* maps of $k$-schemes (in other words, their composition with the structure morphism of $X$ is the identity $\operatorname{Spec}k\to\operatorname{Spec}k$).

Comment: In algebraic terms, this is the fact that $\kappa(x)$ is isomorphic to $k$ not just abstractly as a ring but as a $k$-algebra, using the natural $k$-algebra structure on $\kappa(x)$ coming from the $k$-scheme structure of $X$.

Comment: I think this is precisely my issue: how does the $k$-scheme structure of $X$ induce a natural $k$-algebra structure on $\kappa(x)$?

Comment: The morphism $f:X\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ induces a map $k\to\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ (the induced map on global sections of the structure sheaves).  By restriction, this gives a map $k\to\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for any open $U\subseteq X$, and then a map $k\to\kappa(x)$ for any $x$.

Comment: Note that this is a special case of a slice category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the definition is correct.  When you write something like $\operatorname{Hom}_S(A,B)$ then $A$ and $B$ are assumed to have fixed, chosen morphisms to $S$ that make them into $S$-schemes.  In other words, in the notation $\operatorname{Hom}_S(A,B)$, "$A$" and "$B$" are *abbreviations* for certain morphisms $A\to S$ and $B\to S$ which are actually the objects you are considering morphisms between (in the category of schemes over $S$).  This is no different from how (for instance) a topological space is actually an ordered pair $(X,T)$ where $T$ is a topology on $X$, but people almost always talk about just "$X$" as the topological space, leaving $T$ as implicit.  In the same way, you talk about $A$ and $B$ being schemes over $S$, without explicitly mentioning the chosen morphism to $S$.

In the case of a statement about $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$, $\operatorname{Spec} k$ is being considered as a $k$-scheme via the identity map $\operatorname{Spec} k\to\operatorname{Spec} k$.  Of course this is not the only possible $k$-scheme structure on $\operatorname{Spec} k$ but it is the "default" one that is assumed unless mentioned otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. In the case of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$, Im still not sure how we know that the morphism induced by $A\rightarrow A_{(x)}\rightarrow A_{(x)}/((x)A_{(x)})$ from $\operatorname{Spec} k=\operatorname{Spec} (\kappa(x))\rightarrow X$ commutes with the structure morphism *of* $X$. Put another way, wouldn't  $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ be different for different structure morphisms on $X$? I don't see how we can make a canonical choice for $X$. Please clear this up.

Comment: Here $X$ *comes with* a choice of morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}k$.  It's not just a scheme, but a $k$-scheme.

Comment: Sure I understand this, but when talking about the $k$-points of $X$, people speak as if there is no choice of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ necessary (even more strongly, they identify the set of closed points of $X$ with $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ when $k$ is algebraically closed). And as I mentioned above, I see no reason why $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ should not depend on the choice of morphism $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$ that $X$ comes with.

Comment: It does depend on the choice of morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}k$ that $X$ comes with.  But people are using "$X$" to refer to $X$ together with such a choice.

Comment: This makes sense. One final question, when $k$ is algebraically closed, the set of closed points of X is said to be identified with $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$. But the set of closed points of $X$ does not depend on the structure morphism of $X$, right? How do we reconcile this?

Comment: Right.  So it turns out that regardless of what morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}k$ you pick (assuming it is locally of finite type so that this theorem applies), there will be a canonical bijection between the closed points and $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$.  But the actual set of morphisms $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Spec} k,X)$ may be different for different choices of $k$-scheme structure on $X$ (the morphism $\operatorname{Spec} k\to X$ corresponding to a given closed point may be different for different $k$-scheme structures).